# lshw: command not found

Tags: kali-linux

[image]

Can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here?  I have run updates, upgrades and dist-upgrades, rebooted the system.  Still lshw is not recognized.

I am running Kali rolling dist.  I have never had this problem on any other version of Linux I have tried - is this maybe something specific to Kali?

Comment: when you do your `apt-get` you have to use `apt-get install` so that it knows you're trying to install a package with that name. So the full command should be `apt-get install lshw`

Comment: I kinda wanna delete this question because of the negative reviews, but it has 2500 views, showing that it is a question being searched online regularly enough to help people who may not be members of Superuser.  I remember I found answers on superuser long before I became a member.  I think I will leave it up to help others, and ultimately wait for judgement by the moderators who we worship without criticism.

Comment: @Matthew. Perhaps. Though I came here looking for how to get `lshw` on ubuntu core, so not too useful.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to install the lshw package.

```
$ sudo apt-get install lshw
```

Comment: Great, that worked straight away!  I was confused because the 'apt update' command does not need the 'install' command - we live and learn.

Comment: Exactly, helpful answer :-)